# Submitting/detecting a submit a form by clicking on a CSS button

Tags: html, css, forms

I am experiencing a issue detecting if the submit button was clicked.  I was give the following form by a CSS designer:

```
<form action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Username</label>
        <input name="username" type="text" class="form-control span12">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Password</label>
        <input name="password" type="password" class="form-controlspan12 form-control">
    </div> 
    <a href="" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Sign In</a>    
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</form>
```

I would like submit the captured information by clicking on the Sign In CSS button.  I am used to the usual:

```
<input type="Submit" value="Sign-In>
```

button, but not this is different, I am stuck. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Comment: Change the form action to the correct action, and change `<a>` to `<input type="submit">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try to change

```
<a href="" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Sign In</a>
```

with

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Sign In</button>
```

Furthermore you need to set an `action` attribute on your `form` element

Comment: I think OP is looking for `Form.submit()` of javascript.

Comment: Not so sure, he said he is used to deal with a submit input, so I suppose the problem it's the markup and not the javascript handler.

Answer (score 0):

Give your form and ID = "myform" And try below:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" onClick="document.forms['myform'].submit();" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Sign In</a>
```